# Adding 'tap' to Html through javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add tap to html button through java script so it will start `Onclick` function.
I tried the next code:

```
$("#mydiv").html('bind("'tap'", Onclick)');
```

doest added to the html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the tap event with the `.bind()` method.

```
$("#mydiv").bind('tap', tapHandler); 

function tapHandler()
{
  // handle tap ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most mobile browsers convert taps into click events. So just use

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(){ 
    // do stuff 
});
```

Comment: I need to use it on mobile phone

Comment: The click event works on iOS and Android. "taps" on elements trigger click events automatically.